# Javascript for adding/removing placemarks to Google Earth plug-in map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers, google-earth-plugin

Does anyone know if there is a way to assign a unique ID to placemarks when you create them and add them to a Google earth map via javascript?  Here is an example of the kind of code I'm using to create and add placemarks:

```
    var icon = ge.createIcon('');
    icon.setHref('<url here>');
    var style = ge.createStyle('');
    style.getIconStyle().setIcon(icon);
    style.getIconStyle().setScale(0.65);

    var pm = ge.createPlacemark('');
    pm.setStyleSelector(style);
    pm.setName("Type1");  // <-- NEED ANOTHER METHOD (ex. pm.SetId('uniqueId'))

    var pmPoint = ge.createPoint('');
    pmPoint.setLatitude(35.859545);
    pmPoint.setLongitude(-92.388783);

    pm.setGeometry(pmPoint);
    ge.getFeatures().appendChild(pm);
```

*-------------------------------------------------------------*

I have multiple sets of KmlPlacemarks I want to add to the map, and I don't want to have to assign a unique name to each in order to be able to remove them (mainly because I don't want the name to show up on the map).  I'm trying to remove certain placemarks using the following (incomplete) block of code:

```
var children = ge.getFeatures().getChildNodes();
for(var i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) { 
    var child = children.item(i);
    if(child.getType() == 'KmlPlacemark') {
        if(... ??? ...) {  **// <-- don't want to use if(child.getName().indexOf('criteria') !== -1)**
            ge.getFeatures().removeChild(child);
        }
    }
}
```

*-------------------------------------------------------------*

Does someone know of another way to accomplish this?  I tried using child.getUrl() but that doesn't return anything that I could use to identify which KmlPlacemarks I want to remove from the map...

Or maybe there is a way to set the name visibility on the map to false?

Thanks in advance.

Brandon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a placemark

```
   var pm = ge.createPlacemark('');
```

Use this to set it's 'id'

```
   var pm = ge.createPlacemark('uniqueID');
```

then when you wish to remove it

```
   if(child.getType() == 'KmlPlacemark') {
    if(... ??? ...) {  **// <-- don't want to use if(child.getName().indexOf('criteria') !== -1)**
        ge.getFeatures().removeChild(child);
    }
}
```

becomes

```
   if(child.getType() == 'KmlPlacemark') {
    if(child.getId()=='uniqueID')
        ge.getFeatures().removeChild(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.  There's still something about the code that I'm not understanding though.  Why would it not reload the placemarks if I remove them and then add them back?  I'm using a checkbox selector with an onclick listener to toggle the placemarks on and off the map.  When the checkbox is selected the placemarks appear on the map and they are removed when it's unselected (thanks to your answer), but when I select the checkbox again they don't reappear?  I don't have enough characters left to include the function, but it's basically the same as before (nested in an if-else brackets..)

Comment: Firstly, I would appreciate you marked the question as answered (tick  beside the top left of my answer) - to answer your second question - you cannot reuse 'id's - so you would be better off using - child.setVisibility(true) or false ...... instead of removeChild

Comment: No problem - just marked it.  The child.setVisibility method works perfectly.  Where can I find documentation on all this for future questions?  Thanks a bunch

Comment: https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_placemark-members